# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've read a bunch of threads discussing this problem and I can't find what's wrong with my code.I have an array:

```
    $insert_arr["$key"]['customer']["$cust->Company"]['cpq_id'] = "$cust->CustomerId";
    $insert_arr["$key"]['customer']["$cust->Company"]['shop_cart_id'] = "$cust->ShopCartId";
    $insert_arr["$key"]['customer']["$cust->Company"]['user_id'] = "$cust->UserId";
    $insert_arr["$key"]['customer']["$cust->Company"]['company'] = "$cust->Company";
    $insert_arr["$key"]['customer']["$cust->Company"]['crm_id'] = empty("$cust->CRMAccountId") ? 0 : "$cust->CRMAccountId";
```

A bit later, I have:

```
$q_customer = 'insert into customers
                                 (
                                   cpq_id, 
                                   shopping_cart_id,
                                   user_id,
                                   company_name,
                                   crm_id
                                  )
                                  values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
$sc = $db2->prepare($q_customer);
```

And later still:

```
foreach ($insert_arr as $id => $arr) {
    foreach($arr['customer'] as $c) {
            $sc->execute($c);
    }
}
```

And I always get the error referenced in the title.  I've never used PDO before, and I can't figure out what's wrong.  Help please!

Comment: U didn't defined your parameters ?, ?, ?, ?, ? Check this link http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your parameters before to call the execute method. Your array is also a 3rd dimension type, so you will need to add a foreach.

Like this :

```
foreach ($insert_arr as $id => $arr) {
    foreach($arr['customer'] as $c) {
        $params = array();
        foreach($c as $param => $value) {
            $params[] = $value;
        }
        $sc->execute($params);
    }
}
$sc->execute();
```

Comment: This needs to be `bindValue`, not `bindParam`. Otherwise you'll bind all the parameters to the last value of `$c`

Comment: And shouldn't it be `$value` instead of `$c`?

Comment: `$sc->execute()` needs to be inside the `$arr['customer']` loop.

Comment: JFYI: array_values()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an associative array as the argument to `execute()`, you have to use named placeholders, not `?`. The placeholder names must match the array indexes.

```
$q_customer = 'insert into customers (cpq_id, shopping_cart_id, user_id, company_name, crm_id) values (:cpq_id, :shop_cart_id, :user_id, :company, :crm_id)';
$sc = $db2->prepare($q_customer);
foreach ($insert_arr as $id => $arr) {
    foreach($arr['customer'] as $c) {
            $sc->execute($c);
    }
}
```